# prevent from angular component to be re-rendered

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have a component that is getting as an input a model loaded from the server.
`<app-my-component [data]="myModel"></app-my-component>`
there is another component that reloads the model from the server and basically removes the old one and set the new one (different instance, same data)
Is there any way to prevent reloading the whole component and only refresh the data (or in another way tell angular that both instances are the same... )

I'm using angular 9

Thanks for the helpers

Comment: Can you provide more details?

Comment: What would help you?

Comment: Is there an issue with the reload? Is it a heavy component with loads of processing maybe?

Comment: Reload means what you're are trying to do? Share component structure with HTML, ts file.

Comment: It's a bit complicated to share the HTML, However, I will try to explain more, I have a component that represents a popup of some data (myModel), When I get an updated model, the parent component detects that it's different data and re-render the component, this cause the popup to be closed. So I want to tell somehow that the data wasn't change and no need to re-draw this component

Comment: May be your component need on push() change detection strategy. Or you can check if data is not changed than do not pass it to child component. Without any code its difficult to answer more